# Is this a valid alternative way to calculate plaintexts for a padding oracle attack?

Tags: padding-oracle

I got a lecturer with a slightly way of writing down the padding oracle attack equations than what's considered to be the [standard](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2013/padding-oracle-attacks-in-depth) definition on the internet site like Wikipedia, and I wondered if all the equations are still cryptographically correct.

So it's using uppercase P and C for the plaintext and ciphertext blocks, and lowercase p and c for the plaintext and cipher-text bytes.

[image: Definitions]

PKCS #5 padding is used.  c7 denotes the 8th byte with index 7 of the first block, which is first XOR-ed with a chosen number b and the result of this is sent instead of just a chosen number b:
[image: Example1]
And to calculate the last byte with index 15 of the second block, it just calculated p15 = 1 XOR 2. Without having to do p15 = 1 XOR 2 XOR c7, because the XOR-ed result of c7 and b was sent to the server and not b itself.

Then it knows the decrypted padding number according to PKCS#5 is 0x03 and skips trying to decrypt the byte before the last byte. So there wouldn't be a need to try to pad with the padding lengths 0x02 and 0x03 first like on the Wikipedia example. And directly goes to 2 bytes before that (because of the decrypted 0x3 padding at the last byte) and make the new padding length 0x04.

[image]

It will XOR the last 3 bytes (c5, c6 and c7) wit 0x07, because that's 0x03 XOR-ed with 0x04. And when you XOR with 0x03, it would cancel out the 0x03 already there and then XOR it with 0x04, making the result a 0x04 padding in the modified version.

And then XOR c4 positively with 0x36. And then concludes c4 = 0x36 XOR 0x04 = 0x32

And then the same thing for c3:

[image]

- Is this a valid alternative way to calculate plaintexts for a padding oracle attack?